# iOS text rendering after zoom-in

Tags: ios, uiview, render, cgaffinetransform, text-rendering

I wrote a function to zoom in a UIView using CGAffineTransformScale. After a 2x zoom-in, all text looks really blurred. Images are OK if they are in higher resolution to begin with. Is there a way to re-render all text in proper resolution after zoom in?

**Edit:**
I found a partial solution to my problem:
http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/on-the-importance-of-setting-contentscalefactor-in-catiledlayer-backed-views/

> - (void)didMoveToWindow {
>     self.contentScaleFactor = 2.0; }

By adding the method above in a UIView category, UILabel, UIButton and most other views now render at high resolution. However, this does not affect UITextView or UIWebView. Text within any of these two views are still fuzzy.

So the new question is, how can a UITextView or UIWebView be redrawn at high resolution after zoom-in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can set the `contentScaleFactor` on your UIView to cause it to render its backing view at a higher resolution. Careful on retina devices, though; you want to ensure your new `contentScaleFactor` is at least your `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` . (I would set this before your animation so it is smooth.)

Edit: to be clear, you probably need to set the `contentScaleFactor` of the text view itself to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * 2` in your 2x zoom example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am still confused. Should I set contentScaleFactor of the parent view or the subview? I tried setting the parent view, it didn't work. If that didn't work, setting the direct subviews would not work either, since the actual view with text might be deep in the view hierarchy, so the subview is still considered its ancenster.

Comment: You need to set this on the (deep) text views themselves, unfortunately, at whatever place in the hierarchy they live, because it is those views that do the actual rendering of text to pixels.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! Really helped a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome. It's nice to accept my answer if it helped you solve the question (and will encourage other people to help you in the future).

Comment: I have extended the question. I would like to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Ah, no problem! Yeah, UITextView and UIWebView do their own specialized rendering off-screen. One crazy method you might try is to make those views have frames that are double-size and increase their font size, and then use a transform to scale them back down.